# .htaccess redirect from mysite.com/ to mysite.com/index.php/folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a mirrored site and I need all the visitors to be redirected to a certain page other than the original homepage. But the original site (not the mirror) should continue to behave without changes. Therefore, I need to include a redirect rule in my `.htaccess` based on the referrer. If the visitor targets the mirrored site, I need to redirect. If the visitor lands at the original site, nothing should be done.

How do I implement this?

Comment: yes, this is possible. please provide some more information, what you have tried so far and what is the desired outcome. i.e. mysite.com/foo rewrite to example.com/bar/foo

Comment: It looks like you are asking people to write code for you and it is not the purpose of StackOverflow. Please read this guide http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As of now your question lacks research.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following setup:

fancysite.com - your main site with all the pages

coolname.com - a site that should redirect all requests to your main site

For example, a user requesting www.coolname.com/infos/january.html should be redirected to www.fancysite.com/infos/january.html.

This redirect should be done with a 301 HTTP response (moved permanently) for several reasons, e.g. google preferring it.

To do this on an Apache server, you put a .htaccess file in the root directory of your website (may differ from the root of your account). The server must have the  module mod_rewrite and you must have the rights to use it.

Put the following in your .htaccess to redirect all requests, as you do not want to update it for every new page you put on your site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !fancysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.fancysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The module mod_rewrite is very powerful, have a look at the documentation, if you have the time:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html